# How to ask for a Non Refrigerated bottle of drink

Tags: word-usage

Normally how do you ask for **Not Refrigerated soft drink bottle**, when it is not suitable to use *without ice* as the drink is served in a (may be unopened) bottle, not in a cup.

Is there a common word other than ***Non Refrigerated***?

Comment: As @Brian Hitchcock says, *room temperature*

Comment: In India, they only give the options: cold or *normal*? But I say *cold*! :P

Comment: I would say chilled or non chilled or un-chilled bottle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"room temperature" would be understood as not refrigerated.

For example, if someone asks "Shall I get you a cold one from the fridge?" you might reply "No, thanks; room temperature is OK."

Comment: Can you please add a whole sentence, with `room temperature`?

Comment: "I don't need a cold one; room temperature is fine."